# Error in MySql when trying to delete

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, sql-delete

I am trying to delete comments in a wordpress site marked as 'spam' in the comments_approved table. I keep getting an error even though I can't see anything wrong with the SQL statement. the error is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `` 'delete FROM mysitealias_comments WHERE comment_approved` = 'spam'' `` at line 1

I am using explain as I am just wanting to test before running it. Any ideas why I am getting this error?

```
EXPLAIN delete 
FROM `mysitealias_comments` 
WHERE comment_approved` = 'spam';
```

If I change `delete` to `select *` it is fine, so I'm wondering it must be something to do with the `Delete`?

Sorry I'll ask questions elsewhere now if people deem my coding questions "off topic"!

Comment: You ave an extra `\`` after comment_approved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra tick in your query. Try this:

```
EXPLAIN DELETE
FROM mysitealias_comments 
WHERE comment_approved = 'spam';
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a tick before `comment_approved`

Comment: Can you elaborate with a code example please?...

Comment: The above answer should be more than enough

Comment: Agreed. It was more for your sake though so that you don't get downvoted or flagged by future guests. As it stands, this probably hits the bare minimum threshold to be considered an answer.

Comment: It is called **tick**, not a single quote. I edited and upvoted your answer. You can roll back if you don't like my edit.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for that

Comment: I still get the same error after removing that extra tick.